JS heap out of memory and NextJS Caching
So, I'm working on a website using NextJS and deploying on AWS using a t3.medium instance. I'm relatively new to all of this so I'm not sure of how it's working, but every ~4 days I receive an email saying that one of my instances crashed and when I search for the logs I see this:
ssr-ui-1  | <--- Last few GCs --->
ssr-ui-1  | 
ssr-ui-1  | [114:0x6f85db0] 186260852 ms: Scavenge 1888.7 (1951.2) -> 1881.6 (1950.0) MB, 7.14 / 0.02 ms  (average mu = 0.923, current mu = 0.946) allocation failure; 
ssr-ui-1  | [114:0x6f85db0] 186260933 ms: Scavenge 1888.0 (1950.0) -> 1882.2 (1950.0) MB, 13.80 / 0.11 ms  (average mu = 0.923, current mu = 0.946) allocation failure; 
ssr-ui-1  | [114:0x6f85db0] 186261545 ms: Scavenge 1890.4 (1951.8) -> 1882.3 (1966.2) MB, 24.92 / 0.02 ms  (average mu = 0.923, current mu = 0.946) task; 
ssr-ui-1  | 
ssr-ui-1  | 
ssr-ui-1  | <--- JS stacktrace --->
ssr-ui-1  | 
ssr-ui-1  | FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
ssr-ui-1  | ----- Native stack trace -----
ssr-ui-1  | 
ssr-ui-1  |  1: 0xb86ecf node::OOMErrorHandler(char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [next-server (v14.2.7)]
ssr-ui-1  |  2: 0xef74d0 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [next-server (v14.2.7)]
ssr-ui-1  |  3: 0xef77b7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [next-server (v14.2.7)]
ssr-ui-1  |  4: 0x1109355  [next-server (v14.2.7)]
ssr-ui-1  |  5: 0x11211d8 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [next-server (v14.2.7)]
ssr-ui-1  |  6: 0x1179dac v8::internal::MinorGCJob::Task::RunInternal() [next-server (v14.2.7)]
ssr-ui-1  |  7: 0xd3f5a6  [next-server (v14.2.7)]
ssr-ui-1  |  8: 0xd42b4f node::PerIsolatePlatformData::FlushForegroundTasksInternal() [next-server (v14.2.7)]
ssr-ui-1  |  9: 0x18b8913  [next-server (v14.2.7)]
ssr-ui-1  | 10: 0x18cd38b  [next-server (v14.2.7)]
ssr-ui-1  | 11: 0x18b9637 uv_run [next-server (v14.2.7)]
ssr-ui-1  | 12: 0xbcdbe6 node::SpinEventLoopInternal(node::Environment*) [next-server (v14.2.7)]
ssr-ui-1  | 13: 0xd13054  [next-server (v14.2.7)]
ssr-ui-1  | 14: 0xd13aed node::NodeMainInstance::Run() [next-server (v14.2.7)]
ssr-ui-1  | 15: 0xc77dbf node::Start(int, char**) [next-server (v14.2.7)]
ssr-ui-1  | 16: 0x7f7c47b0f24a  [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
ssr-ui-1  | 17: 0x7f7c47b0f305 __libc_start_main [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
ssr-ui-1  | 18: 0xbcae3e _start [next-server (v14.2.7)]

The website has hundreds of thousands of pages and some routes we decided to make it ISR by passing an empty array to generateStaticParams (which in total would sum around 1000 ISR pages).
When I connect to one of the instances (when it's still working) and write the command docker stats I see one of the columns being Memory Usage / Limit (docker ps return)
Whenever I visit some of these ISR routes I see the memory usage of the second row increase (the nextJS container), but this doesn't make sense to me because the Next documentantion says that the pages are saved on the disk.
I've seen some places that I need to add this line of code:
NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"

but a t3.medium instance has only 4GiB, so setting a higher number (like 8192 for example) shouldn't change anything since this number is not even reachable (right?).
So my questions are:
1: What is this increase of the memory usage that I see when visiting ISR pages? Are they actually being saved on the memory (and on disk)? Is this the expected behavior?
2: Should the caching of fetches also be taken into account? Since in every page there is a fetch for some content data and eventually google bot and other crawlers are accessing thousands of these pages
3: Should I increase the instance type? And how to know if t3.large would be enough for example?
4: Or is it something different from all that was mentioned?
In case it is the max-old-space-sice, should I added it before the next start command?
Thanks in advance!
PS: For now I'm just desabling the ISR pages and waiting to see if it's going to help me. I'm also assuming that there is no obvious code leak like pushing infinite amount of values into a global variable or something like this.
